# Trapped inside the while (true) loop. How to isolate it in a Thread?

Tags: java, while-loop, runnable

Here's the run() method:

```
public void run() {         
    ServerSocket listener = null;           
    if (running == true) {
        btnRun.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            if (!(portField.getText().equals(""))) {                
                String p = portField.getText();
                if (p.matches("[0-9]*")) {                          
                    listener = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(p));                           
                    while (true) {
                        Socket socket = listener.accept();
                        try {
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                            out.println("Hi there, human.");    
                        } finally {
                            socket.close(); 
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only numbers are allowed.");
                    btnRun.setEnabled(true);
                    running = 
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input a port.");
                btnRun.setEnabled(true);
                running = false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | HeadlessException | IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        btnRun.setEnabled(true);
        if (listener != null) {
            try {
                listener.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {                       
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the button:

```
btnRun = new JButton("Run Server");
btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (running == false) {
            running = true;
                run();
        }
    }               
});
```

When the button is clicked, the software freezes (It gets itself trapped running endlessly inside the while (true) loop). As far as I know, I need to run this loop in a separate "thread", and the GUi in other one. But the problem is: I thought I was doing exactly this by implementing the Runnable interface.

How can I isolate this while (true) in a Thread, so that I can USE the rest of the GUI, including the `"JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE"*`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just implementing Runnable is insufficient, you need to explicitly start a thread:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
myThread.start();
```